# How do I find the sum of the values of a colum in Libreoffice Calc (or excel)?

Tags: excel-formula, formula, sumifs, calc

I have date column H, and values in K, and I want to find the sum of the VALUES in K --if H is today.

I tried `=COUNTIFS(K:K,"<>",H:H,">="&TODAY())` 
which gives me the number of entries today, but NOT the sum of their values!
Also, when searching I found some suggestions talking about greater/lesser than today, but I'm looking to compute Today only!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer `SUMPRODUCT` for this.

```
= SUMPRODUCT(K:K,(H:H=TODAY())+0)
```

I recommend narrowing down the full column ranges to where ever your data actually ends (e.g. if you have 100 rows of data, change `K:K` to `K1:K100`).

Comment: Is the +0 just in case there are no matching entries?

Comment: @J.Doe The `+0` is necessary to change an array of logical values (i.e `TRUE` or `FALSE`) to an array of numerical values (i.e. `1` or `0`). Another alternative that you may also see is `--(H:H=TODAY())` which accomplishes the same thing as `(H:H=TODAY())+0`. Has nothing to do with no matching entires.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some reading material about [SumIfs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) ...

```
=SUMIFS(K:K,H:H,TODAY())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIFS(K2:K500,H2:H500,TODAY())
```

First column is text labels, therefore not included.